# How to : jQuery autocomplete for multiple valules with ";" semicolon separator support

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have changed `this.value = terms.join( "; " )` line from comma (,) to (;)
It worked for me for first suggestion. but after semicolon when I type new word no suggestion is shown.I have downloaded [jQueryUI demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( "; " );
                return false;
}
```

Comment: It is not showing any error also in the error console(mozilla)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function split( val ) {
        return val.split( /\;\s*/ );
    }
```

Change this function as I have written above...